# Non-blocking generator on Python

Tags: python, generator, yield

I'm using a generator function from the requests module in a QT-Application, pretty much the same as in the requests-streaming example:

```
import json
import requests

def get_stream():
    r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/stream/20', stream=True)
    for line in r.iter_lines():
        if line:
            yield json.loads(line)

def consume_stream():
    for message in get_stream():
       #do something
```

However, when there is no incoming response (f.e. irregularly incoming tweets from Twitters Streaming API), the generator `get_stream` will block the `consume_stream` method.

This might occur in any situation where a generator does not yield immediately, but hast to wait for incoming messages etc., and therefore blocks the consumer.

Is there any pattern in Python where you can consume a generator in a non-blocking way, i.e. if the generator yields, process it's results, otherwise do something else until the next results are occuring?

Comment: How exactly would you know to continue consuming the generator?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply: the ```consume_stream```-method basically updates a GUI-Widget (TreeModel) and a "Abort"-Button is available. Right now, this buttons block when the ```get_stream``` does not yield anything (e.g. waiting for incoming messages/tweets). I can't modify the ```iter_lines```-method, but I´d like to yield something like "Waiting for tweets.." if the are no incoming tweets, and yield the tweet as soon as there is a new one arriving. So it comes down to the question wether one can control the consumption of a generator inside the consumers for-loop or has to wait..

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [*producer-consumer* pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).  It is commonly implemented in python using a [`Queue`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html).

The producer, typically running in a thread or another process (`Queue` supports either), simply puts messages in the queue. The consumer, whenever it feels like it, pops messages from the queue. This operation supports a `timeout` argument.

Answer (score 1):

As Simeon is asking in the comment, it cannot work as simple as you describe it in your example. There are quite some details you have to take care of. There are different solutions, which make more or less sense, depending on your use case. You don't give much details about what you really want to do, so I will just send you to http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/QTReactor as an example. There a different solutions/frameworks which implement async message queues. And I think, that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you control the generator function, one solution would be to have it throw an exception after a timeout period.  Perhaps something along the lines of:

```
def get_stream(timeout=None):
    while message=read_message(timeout=timout):
        yield message
```

Then have read_message throw a TimeOutException or something if a timeout condition occurs.

Of course, you still have to deal with the logistics of when/how to retry/resume.

Answer (score 0):

You could use async generators as of python 3.6 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/

```py
import json
import requests

async def get_stream():
    r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/stream/20', stream=True)
    for line in r.iter_lines():
        if line:
            yield json.loads(line)

async def consume_stream():
   await for message in get_stream():
       #do something
```